# Как разбить mp4-файл на куски?

Tags: node.js

Имеются ссылки на фильмы/сериалы в формате mp4, хочу на своем сайте их воспроизводить, но бывает моменты, когда видео останавливается и грузится, хочу реализовать как в кинотеатрах. Как можно разбить данную mp4 ссылку на части и воспроизвести?

Comment: Есть специальный плагин ffmpeg вотт с помощью его это делается

Comment: Можно пожалуйста по подробнее?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+split+file+into+chunks+and+make+playlist

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/171213/  вот если хотите подробнее

Comment: В общем, ищите информацию по ffmpeg  если идёт речь по какой то обработке видео то это ОН

Comment: Спасибо! Такой вопрос, а как их потом воспроизводить правильно?